# Pass a list from YAML file to python

Tags: python-3.x, app.yaml

I am creating a web application using googles app engine with the python 3.7 standard environment. I am passing values from the app.yaml file to my main script, however, I cannot seem to pass a list from the yaml file to the main file.

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static


env_variables:
  USERS: 'myemail@email.com'
  USERS2: ['myemai@email.com', 'youremail@email.com']
  USERS3:
  - 'myemail@email.com'
  - 'youremail@email.com'
  USERS4:
    - 'myemail@email.com'
    - 'youremail@email.com'
```

Here is my python script:

```
import os

users = os.environ.get('USERS')
users2 = os.environ.get('USERS2')
users3 = os.environ.get('USERS3')
users4 = os.environ.get('USERS4')
```

The variable users returns `'myemail@email.com'` correctly. Though, `users2`, `users3` and `users4` all return `[]` (an empty list).

Comment: Environment variables are plain text so you have to "invent" data structures by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are text so just getting them with `os.environ` is not going to work.

You claim you are getting empty lists, but I suspect you are actually getting an empty string. There is nothing in Python 3.7's `os.py` that does anything like transformation of a string to (empty) list.

Actually `app.yaml` doesn't seem to be able to handle the sequences in YAML it gets, it could do something like concatenate the sequence entries with a separating character. In any event `USERS3` and `USERS4` are exactly the same, just different indentation (the sequence for USERS2 is of course different)

I suggest you do the above yourself, while also leave out the superfluous quotes in your YAML:

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static


env_variables:
  USERS: myemail@email.com
  USERS2: myemai@email.com:youremail@email.com
  USERS3: myemail@email.com:youremail@email.com
  USERS4: myemail@email.com:youremail@email.com
```

And then in your Python do

```
import os

def listified_env(k):
    x = os.environ.get(k)
    if ':' in x:
        return x.split(':')
    return x

users = listified_env('USERS')
users2 = listified_env('USERS2')
users3 = listified_env('USERS3')
users4 = listified_env('USERS4')
```